# Could a US president be advance pardoned from the result of a senate trial following impeachment?

Tags: united-states, pardon, impeachment, us-senate, us-president

Non-American here, trying to puzzle things out.

If I understand correctly, a US president can grant pardons, but only for federal crimes.

If I understand correctly, impeachment is a political act, and not a crime as such.

Would a senate trial following an impeachment be a federal crime?

If so, could a president be advanced pardoned for such a trial?

I understand that there is uncertainty as to whether a president can pardon him/herself. So, let us posit that they resign and are given a blanket pardon along the lines of that given by Ford to Nixon. Could that pardon apply to a senate trial following impeachment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No

[Section 2, Clause 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Two_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_1:_Command_of_military;_Opinions_of_cabinet_secretaries;_Pardons) says:

> ... and he shall have Power to grant Reprieves and Pardons for Offenses against the United States, except in Cases of Impeachment.

Impeachment is explicitly carved out from the President's power to pardon.